# Get UnProccessed Email Default Email Template In Magento1

Tags: magento-1.9, email, email-templates

I am trying to fetch the email template html with processing the variable. I want forgot_password default template without processing the default variable.

Is it possible to that template without processed variable and with all header footer and css ?